# Improve drawingvisual render's speed

Tags: wpf, performance

I create my own FrameworkElement and override VisualChildrenCount{get;} and GetVisualChild(int index) by returning my own DrawingVisual collection instance.I have override OnRender .

I will add 20-50 DrawingVisuals in this FrameworkElement ,every DrawingVisual will have 2000 line segments.The logic value of these points between 0 to 60000.when I zoom into 1:1 the FrameworkElement 's Height will be 60000, the rending time will be 15 minutes!!

How do I improve the rending performance ?

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of data volume, I would suggest you build a GeometryDrawing and StreamGeometry containing a single PolyLine for each of your points.  Then combine them all together in a single DrawingGroup and display it using a single DrawingVisual.

This would be the XAML:

```
<DrawingVisual Drawing="{Binding CurrentDrawing}" />
```

and this would be the code to update CurrentDrawing:

```
var group = new DrawingGroup();
foreach(var data in myData)
{
  StreamGeometry geo = new StreamGeometry();
  using(geoContext = geo.Open())
  {
    geoContext.BeginFigure(myData.StartPoint, false, false);
    geoContext.PolyLineTo(myData.AdditionalPoints, true, false);
  }
  group.Add(new GeometryDrawing
  {
    Geometry = geo,
    Pen = myData.Pen,
  });
}
CurrentDrawing = group;
...
```

If your data is changing it may be advantageous to create store each GeometryDrawing object separately so it is only necessary to recreate those GeometryDrawings whose source data has changed.

**Update**

You mention in your comment that you need to separately hittest each of the 20-50 data items.  In that case, you probably do want to use a separate `DrawingVisual` for each.  For maximum performance you will want to use `RenderOpen()` with `DrawingContext`:

```
IEnumerable<Visual> BuildVisuals()
{
  return
    from var data in myData
    select BuildVisualForData(data);
}

void BuildVisualForData(MyDataType data)
{
  var geo = new StreamGeometry();
  using(geoContext = geo.Open())
  {
    geoContext.BeginFigure(myData.StartPoint, false, false);
    geoContext.PolyLineTo(myData.AdditionalPoints, true, false);
  }

  var visual = new DrawingVisual();
  using(drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen())
  {
    drawingContext.DrawGeometry(null, myData.Pen, geo);
  }
  return visual;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ray
Thanks for your answer ,I will try it soon.

Comment: I need use hittesting to highlight every visual . If I display them using a single DrawingVisual , I think that it maybe not to be done.

Comment: In that case, put each data item in its own DrawingVisual and use RenderOpen() and DrawingContext.  I've edited my answer to show how this would be done.

Comment: Your Update looks like my existing code .It's performance is very poor.

Comment: I want to know if I can highlight one Geometry in the hittested visual .

Comment: Ive been experimenting with drawing large numbers of polylines, and found that StreamGeometry was the _slowest_ performing option. Fastest was to create a Shape for each polyline, and slower was creating a DrawingVisual with each polyline drawn into it using DrawingContext.DrawGeometry.

Mind you, this is a competition where all options are painfully slow. WPF just doesnt seem to be capable of drawing a lot of squiggly lines (hoping to be corrected).

Comment: @mackenir you're completely wrong, there are a lot of reasons why StreamGeometry is more efficient than Shapes objects.

Comment: I probably screwed something up. However, our company gave up on WPF because there's no way to get more than craptastic performance with non-small numbers of objects. Went for our own DirectX rendering instead.

Comment: @mackenir Ok, this ("there's no way to get more than craptastic performance with non-small numbers of objects") could be corrected; could you can explain better what "way" your company follow now with DirectX?

Answer (score 0):

I need use hittesting to highlight every visual . If I display them using a single DrawingVisual , I think that it maybe not to be done.

For this kind of data volume, I would suggest you build a GeometryDrawing and StreamGeometry containing a single PolyLine for each of your points. Then combine them all together in a single DrawingGroup and display it using a single DrawingVisual.

This would be the XAML:

```
<DrawingVisual Drawing="{Binding CurrentDrawing}" />
```

and this would be the code to update CurrentDrawing:

```
var group = new DrawingGroup();
foreach(var data in myData)
{
  StreamGeometry geo = new StreamGeometry();
  using(geoContext = geo.Open())
  {
    geoContext.BeginFigure(myData.StartPoint, false, false);
    geoContext.PolyLineTo(myData.AdditionalPoints, true, false);
  }
  group.Add(new GeometryDrawing
  {
    Geometry = geo,
    Pen = myData.Pen,
  });
}
CurrentDrawing = group;
...
```

If your data is changing it may be advantageous to create store each GeometryDrawing object separately so it is only necessary to recreate those GeometryDrawings whose source data has changed